# How to add random numbers to mysql row php

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this. I want to add random numbers 1 to 40 to the table. But not just one numbers. for example for video id 1, i want to add 3 numbers. and others are random 2 or 3.

[SEE THE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klATE.png)

Comment: So you want to add multiple categories to a video?

Comment: yes but i dont know how to do.

Comment: What do oyu mean by "like this"? Also, what have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add multiple categories to your videos you have to create an additional table in your database.

You could name it "categories_videos". This table links your videos with your categories.

categories_videos should also have atleast 2 columns: video_id, categorie_id

So now a video can have many categories and a categorie can occur in many videos.